# How would one determine the yield of primary vs. secondary hydrohalogenation addition products?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

For example, if I was to perform the following reaction:

$\ce{CH3CHCH2 + HBr -> CH3CHBrCH3 + CH3CH2CH2Br}$

How would I quantitatively determine the relative yield of the primary and secondary alkyl halides?

Would IR or UV/Vis spectrscopy be able to differentiate between them, or would I have to utilize reactions such as substitution with hydroxyl then oxidation to form ketones and carboxylic acids to differentiate between the two?

Comment: 1H NMR would show the relative yield by comparing the integration of the CHBr proton and the CH2Br protons.. IR or UV/Vis will not do this.

Comment: Or you isolates them (not sure isolate is the term in English. I mean in the current example you get the individual compounds by distillation, if possible. .).